# How to create and install background service in C# .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have created a chat server in C#. It shows all listed IP and Computer name available in LAN to which user can send message. Message can be received when this messaging application is installed on receiver's computer and is open.

Now i want to create and install background service which will be checking for incoming messages. if service got any incoming message then that message will be opened in my application.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
or if you use mono and want linux compatibility http://topshelf-project.com/

Comment: Thank s it was worth useful